# Database import in a different name but the same SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, import, database-administration

I was trying to have the DB copy on the same server but under different name, I am getting this error.

I was doing it by SQL Server Import and Export Wizard by selecting all tables and views (SQL Server 2014)

> Could not connect source component.
> Error 0xc0202009: Source 138 -> Facilities [145]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred.
> Error code: 0x80040E37.
> Error 0xc02020e8: Source 138 -
> Facilities [145]: Opening a rowset for "[dbo].[Facilities]" failed.
> Check that the object exists in the database.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/copy-databases-with-backup-and-restore?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: have you looked into backup and restore?

Comment: sure that might be another option but no i didn't try that.

after i post my question i tried to rerun it by excluding the views (select only all tables) it seems like it is ruing with validation warning. yet it didn't finish